# AWS Linux 2 - Breakdown of Root Volume usage (EBS)?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Question about disk usage (EBS - Root Device)
Running disk-free command shows that 2.5 GB is used on my root device (EBS)
Device is mounted on `/`

[image: diskfree]

However, when I check the folder contents of `/`, it only results to 96kb:
I've also used `a` to check for possible hidden files

[image]

**Question:** The 2.5GB may be for Operating System related files, however is there a way to visualize this? It would be nice to see an exact breakdown of how 2.5GB is used

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the below to see a summary of the sizes for each folder:

```
du -sh /*
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlam - Can you give some more info on why du was able to catch this, while ls was not? thanks!

Comment: This page https://askubuntu.com/questions/186813/why-does-every-directory-have-a-size-4096-bytes-4-k has a good explanation on the folder size that you saw with `ls`.